# Traduko por la angla "jinx"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Mi aŭdis en filmo la frazon "don't jinx it" kaj mi ne trovis kontentigan internaciecan tradukon. [Jen ekzemplo](https://pics.me.me/thumb_when-i-get-good-news-the-us-key-to-success-8738439.png).

Eble tia traduko ne ekzistas; en mia eta regiono oni povas diri tion je tri manieroj. Kaj kelkaj, en la situacio, anstataŭ diri ion kiel "ne malbonŝancigu la aferon!" diras "bonŝancigu ni la aferon per ..." kaj faras geston por forpeli eblan malbonŝancon.

Kiel vi tradukus tiun esprimon, kiel eble plej internacie? (kvankam estus bonege ankaŭ koni la rektajn tradukojn de la lokaj kulturaj superstiĉoj ... sed tio eble ne apartenas al tiu ĉi forumo).

Ĉu "ne malbonŝancigu tion", "ne estu malbonaŭgura", taŭgus?

Comment: Bonaj tradukoj, angle rilatas al "bad luck".

Answer (score 3):

JC Wells in his "Esperanto Dictionary" gives *misŝancigi* for *jinx*, so I'd translate it as *ne misŝancigu ĝin*.